# PHPStorm 8.0.1 and PHPUnit.phar

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I've been trying to setup up PHPUnit in PhpStorm 8.0.1 with no luck. I downloaded phpunit.phar and set the path to the phar in PhpStorm's settings as well as a phpunit configuration file, but when I try to run a test it fails with the following output:

```
/usr/bin/php /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration MyTest /project/MyTest.php
Testing started at 9:31 PM ...

Process finished with exit code 1
Cannot find PHPUnit in include path (.:/usr/share/pear)
```

I'm no expert, but it doesn't seem like it's using the phpunit.phar as the tests run fine when I run

```
$ phpunit
```

in the terminal.

Comment: When you use PHPUnit as a PHAR .. then you should tell PhpStorm where to find your `phpunit.phar` file (e.g. pic #4 here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHPUnit+support+in+PhpStorm )

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problem (not showing hints of PHPUnit_Fremwork_TestCase class) by this:

Download desired version of php.

Then in phpstorm -> **File/Settings../Languages & Frameworks/PHP** tab click "..." button next to "Interpreter" and set path to downloaded PHP.

Next, add the Include path which will point to location where you have phpunit.phar file

Then in phpstorm -> **File/Settings../Languages & Frameworks/PHP/PHPUnit** tab chose radio button "Load from include path" and optionaly set bootstrap and config file.

Now you should not get:

> Cannot find PHPUnit in include path (.:/usr/share/pear)